# how to get data from database and put it on the textbox - vb.net

Tags: vb.net

hello Im trying to get the data from the database when I click like "720" on my comboxbox he will get thee data form "pp12" column in my database and put the data to a textbox, and when i click "1440" on the combobox it will get the data from "pp24" column in DB and put the data in the textbox heres my code thank you guys.

The code:

```
   Private Sub cmbnot_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbnot.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim nsi As String = txtchange.Text

    Select Case nsi

        Case "720"

            With cmd
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandText = "select * from tblCycle"
            End With

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

            If dr.HasRows Then
                While dr.Read
                    txtpd.Text = dr.Item("pp12")
                End While
                dr.Close()
            End If

        Case "1440"

            With cmd
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandText = "Select * from tblCycle"
            End With

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

            If dr.HasRows Then

                While dr.Read
                    txtpd.Text = dr.Item("pp24")
                End While
                dr.Close()
            End If
    End Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say what does not work.

Your code could do with some refactoring to avoid writing the same code twice. Also, you should not have connections hanging around: open the connection, perform the query, close the connection. Your code as it is ends up displaying only the last result from the result set; I have assumed that `txtpd` is set to multiline.

```
Option Strict On

Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Text


Private Sub cmbnot_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbnot.SelectedIndexChanged
     ' should the following be CStr(cmbnot.SelectedItem) ?
     Dim nsi As String = txtchange.Text

     ' We are going to select only the column which is actually needed.
     Dim dbColumn As String = ""

     Select Case nsi
         Case "720"
             dbColumn = "[pp12]"
         Case "1440"
             dbColumn = "[pp24]"
     End Select

     If dbColumn <> "" Then

         Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT {0} FROM [tblCycle]", dbColumn)
         Dim result As New StringBuilder

         ' The "Using" construct takes care of calling .Dispose() for you.
         Using conn As New SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING")
             Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
                 conn.Open()
                 Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                 If dr.HasRows() Then
                     While dr.Read()
                         result.AppendLine(dr.GetString(0))
                     End While
                 End If
                 conn.Close()
             End Using
         End Using

         txtpd.Text = result.ToString()

     End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: thank you it work yeah you're right it should be the combo box thank you

Comment: @user3417541 Please mark it as the answer if it solved the problem for you. That way, other people do not need to take the time to answer your question too.